# Copy-item between server with local administrator credentials

Tags: credentials, powershell-5.0, copy-item

I try to copy file between computers

```
New-PSDrive -Name H -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $ServerDisk -Credential $Credential1 -Persist
New-PSDrive -Name G -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $LocalDir -Credential $Credential2 -Persist
Copy-Item -Force -Verbose -Container -Path G:$FileFolder$ZipFileName -Destination H:$ServerDest 

   Remove-PSDrive H
   Remove-PSDrive G
```

But the file does not copy

Console output:

[image: Console output]

What I make wrong?

For test I add these computers to the same domain and used admin domain account -  with this solution, this script works and copies files.

Comment: Out of date. Today I spent a little more time for testing this script  and it works - copy file but only if it is not in destination (but if the file exist in destination folder it doesn't copy)